# Modify Datetime-local Output format

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, datetime-format

I've searched everywhere but I can't find how to do this.  I'm using the Datetime-local input type using:

```
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

When a user enters the values, it is in this format on screen:

MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM

However when the form is submitted, the datetime-local value appears in this format:

YYYY-MM-DD:THH:MM

I want to keep it in the same format as it's entered.  I've searched but can't find a JavaScript that will grab the value for datetime-local and convert it to the MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM format and set the time to either AM / PM.  Current the time is in Military so anything above 12:59pm will show 13:00 for example.  How can the military time also be converted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = date.getMonth();
  month = month < 10 ? '0'+month : month;
  var date = date.getDate();
  date = date < 10 ? '0' + date : date;
  hours = hours < 10  ? '0' + hours : hours;
  minutes = minutes < 10  ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = month + '/' + date + '/' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date));
```

If you want you can use `moment.js` in that you can format according to your need, but that library is bit heavy if you worried about your website size.

Comment: It's definitely a light webpage so the library wouldn't be needed. What do you mean in the script by 'enter code here' part?  Is that where the field gets called?  How do I call the  new format into a textarea field as the form combines the date and time with additional text before it's submitted

Comment: 'enter code here' was just a type, have edited the answer sorry for that. so you have 2 different fields, 1 for the date and another one for time?

Comment: No it's a single field for both. Datetime-local displays a field to enter both date and time. It's just the value it creates is in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD:THH:MM".  I'm looking to change the value from that to "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM" using JS and have the new value posted into a hidden field called "convertedtime" for example.  That data will then be called using getElementById so it can be combined with other data into a specific structure

Comment: you can extract value using document.getElementById("_you_inpu_id").value and then pass that into the function.

Comment: I tested the above script but it appears to pull the current date and time not the one the user enters into the <input type="datetime-local" /> field.  That field has an Id of Date-Time so it is: <input type="datetime-local" id=Date-Time" />

Comment: Heres the running example,  you can check it out -> https://jsbin.com/hewasetoji/1/edit?html,js,console,output